# How to tap an observable for only the first emitted value

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'd like to tap an observable so that I can execute a method when the first value of the observable emits. I'd like to do this so as to switch on or off a loading state in the UI:

### My current method

```
// Current .create observable
public create = (entry: EntryPatch): Observable<Entry> =>
  this.http.post<NodeResponse<Entry>>(this.serviceEndpoint, entry).pipe(
    map((response: NodeResponse<Entry>) =>
      upsertNode<Entry>(response.data, this.entriesStore)))
```

#### and what I'd like to be able to do with it

```
public create = (entry: EntryPatch): Observable<Entry> =>
  this.http.post<NodeResponse<Entry>>(this.serviceEndpoint, entry).pipe(
    tapFirst(() => this.datastore.loading = true),  // ⬅️ pseudocode
    map((response: NodeResponse<Entry>) =>
      upsertNode<Entry>(response.data, this.entriesStore)),
    finalise(() => this.datastore.loading = false)) // ⬅️ switch off loading indicator
```

What would be the best way to achieve the `.tapFirst` operator (since it doesn't actually exist)?

### Edit

As @Lesiak pointed out below, the structure I've proposed above actually starts the loading indicator *after* the response returns from the server which was not my intention. Hoewver even thought the original question was wrong I'm going to leae it up because the answers that have been posted are still really helpful and tackle both the requests that were implict in this question

a) how to wrap the *whole* observable
b) how to detect the first emission

Comment: To my eyes you try to set loading state too late - when the response arrives.

Comment: ahh - yes, you're absolutely right. I'm going to update the question to make it make more sense as I'm still interested in the answer even though, as you say, I got the problem wrong!

Comment: For your other question: [How to do initialization logic on an observable pipe once per subscription in rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63899782/9423231)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this with combination of `tap()` and `map()` because `map()` passes also index parameter for each `next`:

```
this.http.post()
  .pipe(
    map((response, index) => [response, index]),
    tap(([response, index]) => {
        if (index === 0) { ... }
    }),
  )
  .subscribe(([response] => { ... })
```

You could of course put everything into `map((response, index => {...})` and then just return the same `response` object but it's better to avoid making side-effects in `map()`.

Comment: I did not know that `.map` also returned the index - that's great

Answer (score 3):

I think there are 2 possibilities

**1st: Create a custom operator**

```
function tapOnce<T>(fn: (value) => void) {
    return (source: Observable<any>) =>
        defer(() => {
            let first = true;
            return source.pipe(
                tap<T>((payload) => {
                    if (first) {
                        fn(payload);
                    }
                    first = false;
                })
            );
        });
}
```

See https://indepth.dev/create-a-taponce-custom-rxjs-operator/

**2nd: Split the Observable**

```
$coldObservable = sendMyRequest.pipe(shareReplay(1));

// subscribe to first
$coldObservable.pipe(first()).subscribe(/*do stuff with first emition*/);

// subscribe to all
$coldObservable.subscribe(/* do stuff with all emitions */);
```

Comment: I gave @martin the answer because his was the most elegant solution to the question. However just FYI I will probably end up using `defer` as (as I edited the question to point out) I was actually asking the wrong question in the first place. So thank you